# ola.hallengren - Alternative MySQL scripts!

Tags: mysql, query-performance, optimization, mysql-workbench, maintenance-plans

Having worked with MS SQL for many years and found [ola.hallengren](https://ola.hallengren.com/sql-server-index-and-statistics-maintenance.html) scripts incredibly useful - I find my self in a MySQL environment.

Is there a MySQL alternative to ola.hallengren? - Perhaps someone has created a batch of scripts to show worst performing queries, re-indexing jobs etc that is popular in the area of Database optimisation, maintenance etc.

I've reviewed [Optimize a MySQL Database using MySQL Workbench](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/57250/optimize-a-mysql-database-using-mysql-workbench) - Although useful, doesn't quite give me the flexibility of what I need - that Ola answers with there scripts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might like to visit https://github.com/shlomi-noach/awesome-mysql which is a list of recommended community tools for MySQL.

Specifically the kind of tools you want may be:

- [common_schema](https://github.com/shlomi-noach/common_schema) - DBA's framework for MySQL, providing a function library, views library and QueryScript interpreter.
- [sys](https://github.com/mysql/mysql-sys) - A collection of views, functions and procedures to help MySQL administrators get insight in to MySQL Database usage.
- [Percona Toolkit](https://www.percona.com/software/mysql-tools/percona-toolkit) - a collection of advanced command-line tools to perform a variety of MySQL server and system tasks that are too difficult or complex to perform manually.
- [openark kit](http://code.openark.org/forge/openark-kit) - a set of utilities that solve everyday maintenance tasks, which may be complicated or time consuming to do by hand, written in Python.

Comment: Great thanks Bill. Earlier, I found dbForge Studio - which looks like a more 'together' IDE for MySQL (Compared to Workbench). Not free but looks great and similar to MS Management Studio. I'll go through your links - super helpful, thanks again.